# Can you assign id to tabs in r shiny flexdashboard?

Tags: html, r, flexdashboard

I'm wondering if you can assign id to tabs (and other elements more generally) in r flexdashboard.

I'd like to do this so I can create conditional panels based on which tab is clicked.

I have a very limited knowledge of html.

below is an example code.

````
---
title: "Example"
output: 
    flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        theme: simplex
        orientation: rows
        vertical_layout: fill
        social: menu
        source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(xtable.include.rownames=F)

library(flexdashboard)
```

Column 
-------------------------------------

### Chart 1

```{r}
```

Column {.tabset}
-------------------------------------

### Chart 2

```{r}
```   

### Chart 3

```{r}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works like this:

1. You attribute a 'name' to your column, for example:
   `Column 1` or `Column mycolumn`
2. You refer this column somewhere else in the flexdashboard, with:

   `[This is a column](#column-1)` or 
    `[Show me the column](#column-mycolumn)`

Then, by clicking on whatever is inside the "[ ]", you'll be redirected to whats referenced in the "( )".